# Find how many such complex numbers exist

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, functional-inequalities

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be defined by $f(z)=z^2+iz+1$. How many complex numbers $z$ are there such that $\text{Im}(z)>0$ and both the real and the imaginary parts of $f(z)$ are integers with absolute value at most $10$?
>
> A. $\, 399 \quad$ B. $\, 401 \quad$ C. $\, 413 \quad$ D. $\, 431 \quad$

I cannot make much progress here. I tried putting $z=a+ib$. I also tried putting $z=e^{i\theta}$. But, none of them worked. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: So basically, for $z=x+iy$, $y\gt0$ we need to solve the system of $$x^2-y^2-y+1=n\\x(y+1)=m$$ and $n,m \in \Bbb{Z}$ with $-10\le n,m\le10$..

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Yes. And, $y>0$.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake No, it's $x(2y+1)=m$

Comment: This seems only to have messy solutions. There are $21^2$ possible pairs $m,n$ for the value $f(z)=m+in$. Each yields either 0 or 1 solutions with the imaginary part of $z$ positive. We get 0 solutions for $10-3i,5-2i,6-2i,7-2i,8-2i,9-2i,10-2i$ and $2-i,3-i,4-i,5-i,6-i,7-i,8-i,9-i,10-i,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ and $2+i,3+i,4+i,5+i,6+i,7+i,8+i,9+i,10+i$ and $5+2i,6+2i,7+2i,8+2i,9+2i,10+2i,10+3i$. So 441-42=399 solutions.

Comment: @almagest Can you please post a more detailed answer?